# Jquery Slideshow Plugin: Galleria - change caption style in classic theme

Tags: galleria

I'm loving the galleria jquery plugin, but I'm not liking the way captions show up in the classic theme. I'm looking to move the placement of the info button to the bottom and display the captions at the bottom. I think this is within the css file, but honestly I'm a newb.This http://galleria.io/themes/classic/ is how it looks
I want more of a feel like tn3gallery.com or ad-galler

I'm thinking that I'll need to edit the css, but if someone with some knowledge could point me in the right directions, I'd be appreciative!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited the .galleria-info position and added opacity to it to properly place this
this seems like the long way around as I must actually state the absolute position in regards to the wrapper as to where I want it to sit, but it works for now. Still looking for a cleaner way to do this though.